# How to Login To Wordpress Using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, phantomjs

I was poking around Web Automation and stumbled upon an example where, by using PhantomJS, you can log into a wordpress site and disable the active plugins. The original code is below: ([Or click this for the full tutorial](https://peteris.rocks/blog/configuring-websites-with-phantomjs/))

```
var domain = system.args[1]
var user = system.args[2]
var pass = system.args[3]

var steps = [
  function() {
    console.log('Going to the dashboard')
    page.open("http://"+domain+"/wp-login.php")
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Logging in')
    // notice that user and pass are not available in page.evaluate
    // so we need to pass them as params
    page.evaluate(function(user, pass) {
      document.getElementById('user_login').value = user
      document.getElementById('user_pass').value = pass
      document.getElementById('wp-submit').click()
    }, user, pass)
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Going to the plugins page')
    page.open("http://"+domain+"/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=active")
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Deactivating all plugins')
    page.evaluate(function() {
      document.getElementById('cb-select-all-1').click()
      document.getElementById('bulk-action-selector-top').value = 'deactivate-selected'
      document.getElementById('bulk-action-form').submit()
    })
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Going to the network page')
    page.open("http://"+domain+"/wp-admin/network.php")
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Converting the site to a network')
    page.evaluate(function() {
      document.querySelector('input[name=subdomain_install]').click()
      document.querySelector('#submit').click()
    })
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Done')
  }
]
```

The script is run by using this code from terminal:

```
/tmp/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs wordpress.js blog.example.com admin password
```

(Or something similar).

The major difference between this example is that he is running it from his terminal, and I am trying to have it execute automatically from my web server. As far as I can tell, this means that variables such as `system` and functions such as `click()` do not work. My modifications to the code are as follows:

```
var page = require('webpage').create()
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

var domain = "main.website"
var user = "admin"
var pass = "password"
function click(el){
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    ev.initMouseEvent(
        "click",
        true, true,
        window, null,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        false, false, false, false,
        0, null
    );
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
};

var steps = [
  function() {
    console.log('Going to the dashboard')
    page.open("http://"+domain+"/wp-login.php")
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Logging in')
    // notice that user and pass are not available in page.evaluate
    // so we need to pass them as params
    page.evaluate(function(user, pass) {
      document.getElementById('user_login').value = user
      document.getElementById('user_pass').value = pass
      document.getElementById('wp-submit').click()
    }, user, pass)
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Going to the plugins page')
    page.open('http://' +domain+' /wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=active')
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Deactivating all plugins')
    page.evaluate(function() {
      document.getElementById('cb-select-all-1').click()
      document.getElementById('bulk-action-selector-top').value = 'deactivate-selected'
      document.getElementById('bulk-action-form').submit()
    })
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Going to the network page')
    page.open("http://"+domain+"/wp-admin/network.php")
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Converting the site to a network')
    page.evaluate(function() {
      document.querySelector('input[name=subdomain_install]').click()
      document.querySelector('#submit').click()
    })
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Done')
  }
]
var stepindex = 0
var loading = false
setInterval(executeRequestsStepByStep, 50)

function executeRequestsStepByStep(){
  if (loading == false && steps[stepindex]) {
    steps[stepindex]()
    stepindex++
  }
  if (!steps[stepindex]) {
    phantom.exit()
  }
};
page.onLoadStarted = function() { loading = true }
page.onLoadFinished = function() { loading = false }
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) { console.log(msg) }
```

(I changed the domain name for obvious security purposes)

When running this script, it always returns `Done`, yet nothing at all has been completed. The website to which it is supposed to be connecting is exactly the same as it was before. I am not exactly sure why this may be happening, but every once in a while if I run this script through `SSH` it will alert me that PhantomJS has crashed due to a segmentation error, but Google-ing this proves of little help.

Does anybody have any idea what I need to do in order to accomplish this task? Thank You!

Comment: A couple suggestions on how to debug: 1. add page.onError callback to see if something goes wrong, 2. make screenshots after each step to make sure everything goes as planned, 3. to be on the safe side I'd increase 50ms delay between steps to, say 1000 ms

Comment: I will give these suggestions a try, thanks!

Comment: @Vaviloff When the screenshots are taken the entire thing is gray. Also the only ones that fire are steps number 1, 3, and 5. So 2 and 4 (the most involved) are not firing/fully executing. I added the `page.onError` callback, but nothing has been logged to the console from it.

Comment: If everything is gray, then it means the page was not sucessfully opened and can't be rendered.

Comment: @Vaviloff so a possible solution would be to increase `executeRequestsStepByStep` even more? That doesn't seem to be like an effective method considering everybody has varying internet speeds.